# Sorting repository by more than one attribute

Tags: magento2, search, sort, repository, repositories

I want to sort a repository by more than one attribute. Any ideas of how to achieve this?

What I have so far is this:

```
public function getLatestPosts()
{
  return $this->postRepository
   ->getList($this->buildSearchCriteriaForLatestPosts())
   ->getItems();
}

private function buildSearchCriteriaForLatestPosts()
{
  $this->prepareSearchCriteriaBuilder();
  $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->setPageSize(1);
  return $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
}

private function prepareSearchCriteriaBuilder()
{

   /** @var \Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrder $publishDateOrder */
   $publishDateOrder = $this->sortOrderBuilder
      ->setField(PostInterface::PUBLISH_DATE)
      ->setDirection(SortOrder::SORT_DESC)
      ->create();

   /** @var \Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrder $isFeaturedOrder */
   $isFeaturedOrder = $this->sortOrderBuilder
      ->setField('is_featured')
      ->setDirection(SortOrder::SORT_DESC)
      ->create();

   $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->setSortOrders([$publishDateOrder, $isFeaturedOrder]);
}
```

I dont know why it is not working properly; what I want to achieve is to get the list of Posts sorted by is_featured and created_at in DESC. So even if somehow 2 or more posts are featured, it will display the latest one at the top

Any help will be appreciated! 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take this example

```
public function getLoggedInGroups()
    {
        $notLoggedInFilter[] = $this->filterBuilder
            ->setField(GroupInterface::ID)
            ->setConditionType('neq')
            ->setValue(self::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID)
            ->create();
        $groupAll[] = $this->filterBuilder
            ->setField(GroupInterface::ID)
            ->setConditionType('neq')
            ->setValue(self::CUST_GROUP_ALL)
            ->create();
        $groupNameSortOrder = $this->sortOrderBuilder
            ->setField('customer_group_code')
            ->setAscendingDirection()
            ->create();
        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
            ->addFilters($notLoggedInFilter)
            ->addFilters($groupAll)
            ->addSortOrder($groupNameSortOrder)
            ->create();
        return $this->groupRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
    }
```

Have you tried stacking a second `addSortOrder`?

Comment: Hi Dominic, thanks for your reply. Yes, I have tried stacking a second addSortOrder, but it still doesn't do the work. The thing is that it works if I just have either one sort or another, but not with both

Answer (score 0):

I've found another example but that would suggest you can stack

Here you go

```
    $typeFilter = $this->filterBuilder
                ->setField(TransactionInterface::TXN_TYPE)
                ->setValue($transactionType)
                ->create();
            $idFilter = $this->filterBuilder
                ->setField(TransactionInterface::PAYMENT_ID)
                ->setValue($paymentId)
                ->create();
            $transactionIdSort = $this->sortOrderBuilder
                ->setField('transaction_id')
                ->setDirection(Collection::SORT_ORDER_DESC)
                ->create();
            $createdAtSort = $this->sortOrderBuilder
                ->setField('created_at')
                ->setDirection(Collection::SORT_ORDER_DESC)
                ->create();
            $entity = current(
                $this->getList(
                    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
                        ->addFilters([$typeFilter])
                        ->addFilters([$idFilter])
                        ->addSortOrder($transactionIdSort)
                        ->addSortOrder($createdAtSort)
                        ->create()
                )->getItems()
            );
```